# Can't go to the detail view in Django

Tags: django

my detail view supposed to give me the primary key but why I got this error?

error I got

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'leaveform_detail' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['student\\-leaveform\\-detail/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']
```

models.py

```
class StudentLeave(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    leave_from_date = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    leave_till_date = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    student_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    leave_reason = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.student_name
```

views.py

```
class Student_leaveform_detailView(DetailView):
    model = StudentLeave
    template_name = "attendance/content/student/student_leaveform_detail.html"
```

urls.py

```
path('student-leaveform-detail/<int:pk>/', Student_leaveform_detailView.as_view(), name="leaveform_detail")
```

I used this button to got to the route

```
<a href="{% url 'leaveform_detail' %}" class="btn btn-info mt-3 ml-auto">View</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the ***url parameter***

```
{% url 'leaveform_detail' pk=123 %}
```

Comment: I see! Thanks, I forgot about it haha